# Quickly extracting individual pages from a document

Tags: pdf

Let's say I have created a 100-page book with the `book` document class.

What is the quickest way to extract, say, pages 3, 67-70, and 80 from the book into *six separate PDF files*? Is there any standard tool/script out there that does this very quickly?

Manually doing this through a UI is rather tedious.

Comment: You may also want to look at this tool: [pdfShuffler](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfshuffler/)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You can use the `pdfjam` tool with the syntax

```
pdfjam <input file> <page ranges> -o <output file>
```

and an example of page ranges would be

```
3,67-70,80
```

to extract page 3, pages 67 to 70 and page 80,  and put these pages into a single document. Note however that this will break the hyperlinks in your document.

[edit] pdfjam is actually a front end for pdfpages, suggested in an other answer.

You could also use `pdfseparate` from poppler to burst a document into separate pages. Using

```
pdfseparate <document> 'page_%d.pdf'
```

using the result of `pdfjam` as a document will give you files named page_1.pdf … page_6.pdf containing all the desired pages.

Comment: It will remove all of the hyperlinks, so this method should be discouraged.

Comment: @JongwookChoi: Do you know of a method that does _not_ remove hyperlinks as I thought they all did. I can understand why it might be complicated to retain internal links, but external links should be able to be kept.

Answer (score 40):

You can do this with [the `pdfpages` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/pdfpages).

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
    \includepdf[pages={3,67-70,80}]{<pdf-file>}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If your pdf does not have the same format as `article` (or another easy default), you can use the `fitpaper` key to `\includepdf` to have the paper size automatically adjusted.

Answer (score 19):

You can perform lots of tasks with pdf files using [pdftk](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/). For example,

```
pdftk big_file.pdf cat 3 output page3.pdf
```

creates a new file `page3.pdf` from page 3 of `big_file.pdf`. You can also use ranges; replacing `3` with `67-70` extracts pages 67-70.

Comment: If I remember right there's also a burst directive to split it into single page files.

Comment: Yes. But: not avalable in Centos7

Answer (score 7):

Use [PDFtk](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) (the manual is [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/pdftk.1.html)),

```
pdftk "input.pdf" cat 3 67-70 80 output "output.pdf"
```

Answer (score 2):

[PDFsam](http://www.pdfsam.org/) (PDF split and merge) is a little more general tool I use often. It now comes in different flavors, with

> PDFsam Basic, a free and open source solution for casual users. Split,
> merge, mix, extract pages and rotate PDF files.

Comment: PDFsam Basic is free and it's easy to use. thanks.