# search for and highlight words/numbers in pdfpages while only printing highlighted pages

Tags: pdfpages, programming, automation, scripts

I have a project where it would be *very* helpful to be able to include pdf pages with certain text and or number highlighted, and in addition limit the pages output to those which have the highlighted terms.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage {fontspec} 
\usepackage{pdfpages}

{phrase to be searched,word,word2,word3,another phrase, 555-222-1212}

\begin{document}

\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand={\thispagestyle{empty}},width=\textwidth]{First.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand={\thispagestyle{empty}},width=\textwidth]{Second.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand={\thispagestyle{empty}},width=\textwidth]{Third.pdf}

\end{document}
```

So that the output would be the combined contents of First.pdf, Second.pdf and Third.pdf, but only the pages with the terms "phrase to be searched,word,word2,word3,another phrase, 555-222-1212" included, and with those terms background highlighted.

The closest to this I have found is [automated indexing against keyword file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136109/automated-indexing-against-keyword-file) and I upon reading it found myself unsure how one would make a complete example. There could be both an ocr and a pdf-already-with-text solution to the question.  I know this is a lot to ask, but I have been surprised here before with the things that are possible with TeX.

[How to highlight keywords?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22598/how-to-highlight-keywords) might be relevant to the problem.

[make soul highlight span lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/282386/make-soul-highlight-span-lines) describes how to use the soul package to highlight text.

Or [add-comments-to-pdf-files-automagically-with-regular-expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427034/add-comments-to-pdf-files-automagically-with-regular-expressions)

Looks like pdfjam could extract pages from a pdf: [quickly-extracting-individual-pages-from-a-document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79623/quickly-extracting-individual-pages-from-a-document/79626#79626)

> As an alternative: Could this be done by extracting the text from the pdf  files, and then re-assembling the document? (I realize that most/all formatting would be lost)

Comment: Locating text or numbers withing images is called OCR (Optical Character Recognition).

Comment: I guess OCR could be part of this question.

Comment: pdfgrep (https://pdfgrep.org/) can tell you the page numbers for the occurences of text strings. With `\write18` you could call it from your TeX file. Don't know about the highlighting.

Comment: are you on windows?

Comment: No, I'm on debian/ubuntu using windowmaker